# Números perfeitos

Tags: algoritmo, loop, for, visualg

```
algoritmo "numeros_perfeitos"
var
c, n:inteiro
nv, np, npv:real
inicio
para n <- 1 ate 100 faca
  para c <- 1 ate n faca
     se n % c = 0 entao
        nv <- n / c
        se nv < n entao
           np <- nv + np
        fimse
     fimse
  fimpara
  se np = n entao
     escreva(np)
  fimse
  np <- 0
  nv <- 0
fimpara
fimalgoritmo
```

Eu escrevi esse código para esse exercício:

> Escrever um algoritmo que gera e escreve os 4 primeiros números
>   perfeitos. Um número perfeito é aquele que é igual a soma dos seus
>   divisores. Ex.: 6 = 1+2+3; 28= 1+2+4+7+14.

Porém ele trava quanto coloco de n ate 10000 eu fiz algo errado? E por que ele executa muitos ciclos na estrutura interna (acho que são 100000 ciclos)? Minha logica foi ruim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente está demorando para executar, pois ele vai executar somatório de 1 -> n. Ou seja, para um caso em que N = 10000, ele executa 50005000 vezes esse teu ciclo. Então ele trava, exatamente, por demorar pra executar essa quantidade de loops.
Algumas formas de você melhorar esse algoritmo são:

- Sempre que tu encontrar o quarto número perfeito, interromper a execução do laço: faça uma verificação se foram encontrados 4 números, se sim, utilize o [comando interrompa](http://www.apoioinformatica.inf.br/produtos/item/15-comando-interrompa) no laço mais externo
- Você não precisa executar o laço mais interno de 1 até n, mas sim de 2 até n^1/2: Primeiro que 1 sempre dividirá um número, então, ao invés de iniciar a sua soma com 0, você pode iniciar com 1. Segundo que multiplicação é uma operação complementar, então se você sabe um dos fatores, você saberá os dois (em caso de multiplicação de apenas 2 termos), isso significa que você não precisa descobrir TODOS os divisores de N, mas apenas METADE deles, para isso, você tira a raíz quadrada desse número. Feito isso, você tem que somar os dois fatores a sua conta, somando C e N/C, quando N%C = 0.

Comment: Muito obrigado entendi, sera que e normal cometer esse erro e eu foi muito burro mesmo?

Comment: Faz parte do aprendizado, o importante é sempre procurar crescer. (:

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -3):

Espero que ajude. Código feito com java script:

```js
function numeroPerfeito(n) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let x = 1; x <= (n / 2); x++) {
    if (!(n % x)) {
      sum += x;
    }
  }

  return sum == n;
}
```

Comment: A pergunta não foi feita e não foi solicitado resposta em [tag:javascript] ou outra linguagem que não seja [tag:visualg]. Leia [answer] e faça o nosso [tour].